# Unity 5 and NetworkManager

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, unity-networking

When i use Unity 3d version < 5.0. I use:
- Network.InitializeServer
- MasterServer.RegisterHost
- MasterServer.PollHostList
- Network View component.
But... When I use Unity 3d version >= 5.0, I got the messenger:
"Network Views (Legacy)
(For new projects, you should use the new networking system introduced in 5.1. This information is for legacy projects using the old networking system.)"
I'm using C# script in Unity 5.1.1
So... Every body, please help me. How to use that feature in unity 5.0 or laster?
Thank every body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use old Network.In Unity 5.1 they added new [Network System](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/12/announcing-unet-new-unity-multiplayer-technology/) I recommend you to use the new one but legacy (old Networking)is also useable.